# Show username after posting (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session-variables

I am working on a small community page where users will be able to post news, pictures, and comment on them. The problem where I am stuck is, whenever a user posts an entry, I want of course the username to be displayed next to the entry. 
I am working with multiple tables here, one that stores the user info, and some that store the entry info (news, comments, pictures). 
Now whenever a user posts something, I want to get his user ID out of the table USER, so that I can INSERT a new line INTO my table (in this case) NEWS, which wants the values Text, Title and U_ID as foreign key. 
I am working with sessions, and since I had no problem simply displaying the name of the login user, I tried to use that user to select "his" row from the table and put the result into a variable ($uid) which I was hoping to use in another query for the INSERT INTO. However, according to the error message I get, something is wrong with my first query. Can anyone help?

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

session_start();

        if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
           $user = $_SESSION['user'];

        $sqluser = "SELECT FROM USER USER_ID
                    WHERE Name = '$user'";

        $userresult = $conn->query($sqluser)  or die($conn->error);

        while($row = $userresult->fetch_assoc()){
             $uid = $row["USER_ID"];
            }
        } else {

             header('Location: login.php');
        }

        if (isset($_POST["title"], $_POST["text"])) {
            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["title"]);
            $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["text"]);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO NEWS (Titel, Text, U_ID) 
                    VALUES ('$title', '$text', '$uid')";
            }
    $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: This is the error message I get:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM USER USER_ID WHERE Name = 'username'' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

I think there is mistake in your query

```
 $sqluser = "SELECT FROM USER USER_ID WHERE Name = '$user'";
```

It should be like this

```
 $sqluser = "SELECT USER_ID FROM USER WHERE Name = '$user'";
```

Comment: Are you kidding.. all of this because a stupid typo I didn't see?? XD
Thanks, I fixed it and will try again

Comment: Yes, it happens sometimes.